# Turtlebot amcl demo, using map-files from selected directory?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

map files created with the turtlebot 'SLAM map building' tutorial are stored in the /tmp/ directory. I have tried moving the generated files to my home directory and the run the 'amcl-navigation demo' pointing to the files in this directory but the map-server does'nt seem to accept this. How can i store and reuse different mapfiles?

roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/turtlebot/freja02.yaml

HFOR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11366/turtlebot-amcl-demo,-using-map-files-from-selected-directory?/) by [hfor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1139/hfor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

as @tfoote pointed out, the command should look like:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/turtlebot/freja02.yaml
```

Also, make sure your `.yaml` file points out the right location of `.pgm` file. Suppose you have `freja02.pgm` also in the home directory, you might want to something like:

```
emacs freja02.yaml &
```

This will open a text editor, then correct perhaps the 1st line where describes the path of `.pgm` file as:

```
image: /home/turtlebot/freja02.pgm
```

then save file by `Ctrl-s` (pressing control key and s). Close the window, and run the `.launch` file again.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you move the map files do you move both the yaml and the binary file next to it?  They yaml file is just the metainformation for the map.

Also if it's in your home directory it should be /home/turtlebot/freja02.yaml

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1